# How can I select first class in div block which contains many same classes?

Tags: jquery

I have HMTL example:

```
<div class='box'>
    <div>something</div>
    <p>something</p>
    <div>
       <ul>
         <li>first ul li</li>
       </ul>
       <div>
       <ul>
         <li>second ul li</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
    </div>
    <div> 
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li>third ul li</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
    <ul><li>fourth ul li</li></ul>
</div>
```

For example: I want to select first ul only.
I have used first() but It did not work.

Can you give me suggestion?

Comment: You're gonna need to show us some of your Javascript.

Comment: Well show us how you used `first()`

Comment: I have used: $('.box ul').first()

Comment: @MinhAnh It works here - https://jsfiddle.net/ydqqgjnf/

Comment: oh. Impossible. I have appended it to another div, it appended all ul.

Comment: @JoshCrozier: oh it works. Thank you. I did not understand why when I put it in condition, it appended all.